# How to add “input” event listeners on the username and password input elements using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
document.getElementById("txt").addEventListener("focus", function(){
    if(document.getElementById("txt").value.valid==true){
    this.style.border="solid green 2px"  
    }else{
    this.style.border="solid red 2px"  
    }
});

document.getElementById("pwd").addEventListener("focus", function(){
    this.style.border="solid green 2px"  });

document.getElementById("txt").addEventListener("blur", function(){
    this.style.border="solid white 2px";
    this.style.boxShadow="0 0 5px white";
  });

document.getElementById("pwd").addEventListener("blur", function(){
    this.style.border="solid white 2px";
    this.style.boxShadow="0 0 5px white";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="form">
    <input type="text" minlength="6" maxlength="10" placeholder="User name" id="txt" required>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="password" minlength="8" maxlength="15" placeholder="Password" id="pwd" required>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script src="script 2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I NEED TO..

Add “input” event listeners on the username and password input elements using JavaScript.

Create an event handler for the “input” event that does the following: 
Use the event object’s target property to get the input element on which this event is active.

Check if the input is valid for this element by using the validity property of the event.target object (event.target.validity.valid). If valid,

Change the styles of the input element using the style property of event.target object (event.target.style).

[like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJZvw.png)

Comment: `document.getElementById("txt").value.valid`. return `undefined`. Please give example validation logic.

Comment: What is the problem with the above code and what is your question?

Comment: I want to achieve the same form as the image with event listeners and validate it

Answer (score 0):

Use `.addEventListener("input", function() { });` to do something when the input changes.

```js
var txt = document.getElementById("txt");
var pwd = document.getElementById("pwd");

txt.addEventListener("input", function() {
  if (this.validity.valid) {
    this.style.border = "2px solid green";
  }
});

pwd.addEventListener("input", function() {
  if (this.validity.valid) {
    this.style.border = "2px solid red";
  }
});

txt.addEventListener("focus", function() {
  if (txt.value.valid == true) {
    this.style.border = "solid green 2px"
  } else {
    this.style.border = "solid red 2px"
  }
});

pwd.addEventListener("focus", function() {
  this.style.border = "solid green 2px"
});

txt.addEventListener("blur", function() {
  this.style.border = "solid white 2px";
  this.style.boxShadow = "0 0 5px white";
});

txt.addEventListener("blur", function() {
  this.style.border = "solid white 2px";
  this.style.boxShadow = "0 0 5px white";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <form id="form">
    <input type="text" minlength="6" maxlength="10" placeholder="User name" id="txt" required>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="password" minlength="8" maxlength="15" placeholder="Password" id="pwd" required>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

  <script src="script 2.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: not achieving the same as the image.. but thank you!

Comment: @AadiYogi please comment what it isn't achieving so I can fix my answer so that it does work for you

Answer (score 0):

Aniket G. said right you need to have have input eventListener. You don't need to have the `focus` and `blur` event. And you don't need to attach event listener one by one just create an array of elements and loop though it to `addEventListener`

```js
var txt = document.getElementById("txt");
var pwd = document.getElementById("pwd");

[txt,pwd].forEach(elm => {
   elm.addEventListener("input", function() {
    this.style.border = (this.validity.valid) ? "2px solid red":"solid green 2px";
  });
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="form">
    <input type="text" minlength="6" maxlength="10" placeholder="User name" id="txt" required>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="password" minlength="8" maxlength="15" placeholder="Password" id="pwd" required>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script src="script 2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```